# Set focus to element

Tags: c#, wpf, setfocus

There are a button and a textbox. I added a "KeyDown" event to textbox so that when "enter" is pressed button gets clicked. Good, then I tried to give focus to textbox again but failed. In the code below I tried three ways but neither is working.

```
private void txt_addRemove_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {               
        btn_BC_add.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));

        // 1.way
        // IInputElement focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(txt_addRemove);
        // 2.way
        // Keyboard.Focus(txt_addRemove);
        // 3.way
        // txt_addRemove.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of catching the Return key, I'd just set the [IsDefault property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
if (!textBox1.Focus())
   {
       textBox1.Focus();
   }
```

What this does:
1. We check if the textbox is NOT focused.
2. If it is not focused, focus the control.

EDIT: How about this:

```
btn_BC_add.PerformClick()
```

Comment: Why should this work if the "3.way" in his question does not work?

Comment: Okai, I've read through your post again and I think i know the solution: use btn_BC_add.PerformClick(); instead :).

Comment: What namespace is needed for `PerformClick()` otherwise it is undefined here?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms - EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try focusing the textbox after the event handler is finished using:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { txt_addRemove.Focus(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

couldnt you also try changing the focus from the button event handler? this might not be desirable if you dont want the focus to be on your textbox after a normal click of the button, but it should work.

Im guessing that your button click is generating a post back before the focus can be changed